# Plotting three variables on a line plot but one of the variables stays parallel to the x axis

Tags: matplotlib, visualization

Want to plot a line plot with three variables ,all three when plotted alone show a curve but when plotted together one of them shows a straight line,  the index of the three data are in date time format .
[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8), dpi=150)
  
nig_confz['count'].plot(label='confirmed', color='orange', linewidth=3)
nig_recovs['count'].plot(label='recovered',linewidth=3)
nig_deaths['count'].plot(label='deaths',color='green',linewidth=3)

plt.xlabel('Date')
  
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score 0):

the columns from the time series data were on different scale , so the columns have to be standardized

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
# since we have a datetime index scale only the count column 

nig_confz['count'] = scaler.fit_transform(nig_confz['count'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
nig_recovs['count']= scaler.fit_transform(nig_recovs['count'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
nig_deaths['count'] = scaler.fit_transform(nig_deaths['count'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
```